# Flutter - Cubit - loaded state - managing redirection to a page - 2 builds of the page are made

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, cubit, flutter-reactive-forms

Sorry for my english I'm French.

I develop in Flutter (dart) and I experience a strange behavior in my code using Cubit (Bloc) when I want to redirect to a page after a form submission (with "Reactive forms" package, but also with classic form)  and the step of the Cubit loaded state: I see 2 calls to the page (2 builds) which gives a sort of "flapping" effect which means that the final user sees the interface charging twice.

It's my first application in Flutter.

I created an application containing a login form: when the form is submitted I print another form.

At the beginning of my application I was using "auto_route" package and I obtained a refresh of the page each time I clicked inside the text field after the login process. So I was not able to write anything inside the text field.

I was thinking that the problem came from the "Reactive forms" package so I opened an issue to the github repository of this package: [issue opened](https://github.com/joanpablo/reactive_forms/issues/145)

But as I didn't see where was the problem I came back to a much more basic development for my application and also a more basic method for managing the pages routing in order to explain my problem to the maintainer of the "Reactive forms" package, a really nice guy which really tried to help me.

But even the maintainer does not understand why I have this problem.

Now I reduced my more simple code in one page.

For the moment I don't have the problem when I clicked inside the text field but I see that interface is built twice and the Cubit loaded state which maybe explains why I had the initial problem.

So now I try to understand why the interface is built twice before debugging my original code.

I think my main problem is that the Cubit loaded state is waiting a synchronous widget return but when I try to redirect to a another page it needs an asynchronous action (with "auto_route" package or more simply using "Navigator.push()" action).

But I don't know how to call a Future inside a Cubit loaded state which wait a classic Widget.

I tried this:

```dart
  Widget myAuthBuildLoaded(context) {
    Timer.run(() {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(1)));
    });
    return Container();
  }
```

So I think that the returned widget "return Container()" build the interface one time ans after the Navigator.push() build the interface another time.
I tried to directly return "Navigator.push" but I have an error (because it is not a Widget).

I would really appreciate some help for this problem.
Thanks.

Here is my full code (the more simple version).

My pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: myapi
description: MyApi mobile application
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  bloc: ^7.0.0
  flutter_bloc: ^7.0.0
  reactive_forms: ^10.0.3

dependency_overrides:

dev_dependencies:

flutter:
  generate: true
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

My code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:reactive_forms/reactive_forms.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(Application());
}

class AppColors {
  static const Color PRIMARY_COLOR = Colors.blue;
  static const Color ACCENT_COLOR = Colors.black;
  static const Color BG_COLOR_01 = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
  static const Color BG_COLOR_02 = Color(0xFFDDE7DD);
  static const Color BG_COLOR_03 = Color(0xFFCCCFBD);
  static const Color TXT_COLOR_01 = Colors.black;
}

class Application extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ApplicationState createState() => ApplicationState();
}

class ApplicationState extends State<Application> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    log("Build MyApi Application");

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MYAPI',
      showSemanticsDebugger: false,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(0),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int indexSelected;
  HomePage(this.indexSelected) : super();

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<Widget> _pages = [];
  int _indexSelected = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pages.addAll([
      AuthPage(),
      ConnectedFirstPage(),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _indexSelected = widget.indexSelected;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: _pages.elementAt(_indexSelected),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthPage extends StatelessWidget {
  AuthPage() : super();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    log("Build AuthPage");

    final bool isPortrait = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait;
    final FormGroup form = FormGroup({
      'client_code': FormControl(validators: [Validators.required]),
    });
    AuthCubit? authCubit;
    return BlocProvider<AuthCubit>(
      create: (context) {
        authCubit = AuthCubit(Auth(), form);
        // authCubit!.defineFormLogIn();
        // form = authCubit!.form;
        return authCubit!;
      },
      // child: Scaffold(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Overlay(
          initialEntries: [
            OverlayEntry(
              builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                body: Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 150, 10, 10),
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 2, 10, 2),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(height: 35.0),
                                      Container(
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              children: [
                                                Wrap(
                                                  children: [
                                                    Container(
                                                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                                      child: RichText(
                                                        text: TextSpan(
                                                          text: "Login",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: 26,
                                                            fontFamily: 'Times',
                                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                                            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                                      Container(
                                        child: FractionallySizedBox(
                                          widthFactor: 0.7,
                                          // child: Form(
                                          child: ReactiveForm(
                                            formGroup: form,
                                            // formGroup: authCubit!.form!,
                                            // key: _formKey,
                                            child: Column(
                                              children: [
                                                BlocConsumer<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
                                                  listener: (context, state) {
                                                    if (state is AuthError) {
                                                      myAuthBuildError(context, state.message);
                                                    }
                                                  },
                                                  builder: (context, state) {
                                                    if (state is AuthInitial) {
                                                      return myAuthBuildInitial(context);
                                                    } else if (state is AuthLoading) {
                                                      return myAuthBuildLoading(context);
                                                    } else if (state is AuthLoaded) {
                                                      return myAuthBuildLoaded(context);
                                                    } else {
                                                      // In case of error we call the initial widget here and we handle the error with the above listener
                                                      return myAuthBuildInitial(context);
                                                    }
                                                  },
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        child: SizedBox(height: 2.0),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      // ),
    );
  }

  void myAuthFormSubmit(context) async {
    log("Form 'client code' submitted!");
    final authCubit = BlocProvider.of<AuthCubit>(context);
    try {
      await authCubit.logIn();
    } on FormatException catch (e) {
      myAuthBuildError(context, e.message);
    }
  }

  Widget myAuthBuildInitial(context) {
    final form = BlocProvider.of<AuthCubit>(context).form;
    return ReactiveFormBuilder(
      form: () => form!,
      // form: form,
      builder: (context, form, child) {
        String _fieldName = "client_code";
        String _fieldTitle = "Enter your client code";
        String _msgRequired = "required field";
        double _padding = 10.0;
        return Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    // MyFormInputText(
                    //   fieldName: "client_code",
                    //   fieldTitle: "client code",
                    //   msgRequired: "required field",
                    //   isRequired: true,
                    // ),
                    Container(
                      height: 60.0,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: ReactiveTextField(
                              // autofocus: true,
                              formControlName: _fieldName,
                              validationMessages: (control) => {ValidationMessage.required: _msgRequired},
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                fontFamily: 'Times',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(_padding),
                                focusColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                hoverColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                hintText: _fieldTitle,
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                ReactiveFormConsumer(
                  builder: (context, form, child) {
                    String mybuttonTitle = "Validate";
                    double mywidth = 100.0;
                    double myheight = 50.0;
                    double myradius = 20.0;
                    double myfontSize = 20;
                    String myfontFamily = "Times";
                    FontWeight myfontWeight = FontWeight.w400;
                    Color mybackgroundColor = AppColors.PRIMARY_COLOR;
                    Color mytextColor = Colors.white;
                    // return MyButtonValidate(buttonContext: context, buttonAction: () => myAuthFormSubmit(context));
                    return Container(
                      width: mywidth,
                      height: myheight,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextButton(
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((state) {
                                  return mytextColor;
                                }),
                                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((state) {
                                  return mybackgroundColor;
                                }),
                                overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((state) {
                                  return mybackgroundColor;
                                }),
                                padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0, horizontal: 2.0)),
                                textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                  TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: myfontSize,
                                    fontFamily: myfontFamily,
                                    fontWeight: myfontWeight,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                shape: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((state) {
                                  if (state.contains(MaterialState.disabled) && form != null && form.valid) {
                                    return RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(myradius),
                                      side: BorderSide(
                                        color: AppColors.ACCENT_COLOR.withAlpha(90),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  } else {
                                    return RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(myradius),
                                      side: BorderSide(
                                        color: mybackgroundColor,
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }
                                }),
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Text(mybuttonTitle),
                                ],
                              ),
                              onPressed: () => myAuthFormSubmit(context),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget myAuthBuildLoading(context) {
    return CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor);
  }

  Widget myAuthBuildLoaded(context) {
    Timer.run(() {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(1)));
    });
    return Container();
  }

  myAuthBuildError(context, message) {
    return Text("Error", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red));
  }
}

class AuthCubit extends Cubit<AuthState> {
  final Auth? _auth;
  final FormGroup? form;

  String? _clientCode = "";
  AuthCubit(this._auth, this.form) : super(AuthInitial());

  // bool _isFormValid = false;

  Auth get getAuth => _auth!;

  // defineFormLogIn() {
  //   log("Info: defineFormLogIn");
  //   form = FormGroup({
  //     'client_code': FormControl(validators: [Validators.required]),
  //   });
  // }

  Future<void> logIn() async {
    _clientCode = form!.control("client_code").value.toString();
    log("Info: Form - _clientCode=$_clientCode");
    try {
      emit(AuthLoading());
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
        log("AuthCubit - logIn: Handle something!");
      });
      emit(AuthLoaded(_auth!));
    } on Exception {
      emit(AuthError("impossible to connect to myapi"));
    }
  }
}

@immutable
abstract class AuthState {
  const AuthState();
}

class AuthInitial extends AuthState {
  const AuthInitial();
}

class AuthLoading extends AuthState {
  const AuthLoading();
}

class AuthLoaded extends AuthState {
  final Auth auth;
  const AuthLoaded(this.auth);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object o) {
    if (identical(this, o)) return true;

    return o is AuthLoaded && o.auth == auth;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => auth.hashCode;
}

class AuthError extends AuthState {
  final String message;
  const AuthError(this.message);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object o) {
    if (identical(this, o)) return true;

    return o is AuthError && o.message == message;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => message.hashCode;
}

class Auth {
  String _clientCode = "";
  String state = "not connected";
  bool isConnected = false;

  Auth();
}

class ConnectedFirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  ConnectedFirstPage() : super();

  final FormGroup form = FormGroup({
    'event_id': FormControl(),
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    log("Build ConnectedFirstPage");
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          // child: ReactiveForm(
          //   formGroup: form,
          //   child: ReactiveTextField(
          //     formControlName: "event_id",
          //     style: TextStyle(
          //       fontSize: 15,
          //       color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          //       fontFamily: 'Times',
          //       fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          //     ),
          //     decoration: InputDecoration(
          //       hintText: "My event",
          //     ),
          //   ),
          // ),

          child: ReactiveFormBuilder(
            form: () => form,
            builder: (context, form, child) {
              return ReactiveTextField(
                formControlName: "event_id",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  fontFamily: 'Times',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Event ID",
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My "flutter doctor -v" result:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on macOS 11.2.1 20D74 darwin-arm, locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 2.0.6 at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/1.22.6/flutter
    • Framework revision 1d9032c7e1 (4 weeks ago), 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
    • Engine revision 05e680e202
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mycompany/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)              • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Even when I replace the form by a Text widget in the connected page I have the problem.
In the debug console I see that:
2 [log] Build ConnectedFirstPage

In the class "ConnectedFirstPage" I replaced "child: ReactiveFormBuilder ..." by:


child: Text("Connected", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red)),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that I have solved your problem. This problem lies within your `BlocConsumer` widget.

The `builder` method of the `BlocConsumer` widget is called multiple times whenever the state of your `AuthCubit` changes. This results in `myAuthBuildLoaded()` pushing the page twice. That is what is causing the flickering effect. To avoid this, see the example below. The `listener` method of the `BlocConsumer` widget is only called once on every state change. That should revolve your problem.

```dart
BlocConsumer<AuthCubit,AuthState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    if (state is AuthError) {
      myAuthBuildError(context, state.message);
    } //
    // Add this here.
    else if (state is AuthLoaded) {
      myAuthBuildLoaded(context);
    }
  },
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is AuthInitial) {
      return myAuthBuildInitial(context);
    } // 
    else if (state is AuthLoading) {
      return myAuthBuildLoading(context);
    } //
    // Remove this here.
    // else if (state is AuthLoaded) {
    //  return myAuthBuildLoaded(context);
    //} //
    else {
      // In case of error we call the initial widget here and we handle the
      // error with the above listener
      return myAuthBuildInitial(context);
    }
  },
),
```

I am not exactly sure if this was the problem you were trying to solve. Let me know if I can help in any other way!

Comment: YES!!! This is the solution! You saved my life! :-)